# Multiple Agent Jobs Running same SSIS Package

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-agent, etl

I have the following doubt, is there a possibility to have faild a Job when are running simultaneously as the following example:

4 SQL Agent Jobs running the same SSIS in different schedules, I've heard that the max number of possible execution is 4, but not sure if that is a parameter that can be changed or not, if so, have you heard about it ?

Answer (score 2):

You may be referring to the MaxConcurrentExecutables property.  It controls how many parallel threads may run during the execution of the package and it can be changed on the package properties.

[image: MaxConcurrentExecutables]

The default is -1 which translates to 'how many cores ya got'+2.
I haven't ever heard of anything that would stop either the SQL Agent or the Integration Server to limit the number of concurrent executions of a single package.

Check out this [article on MaxConcurrentExecutables](http://ssis-2008.blogspot.com/2010/08/parallel-processing.html).